# Cloud9 git workspace: how to create?

Tags: git, cloud9-ide

I'm following Cloud9 tutorial and one of the steps is 'Create git workspace'.
But in my contol panel I see only 'Hosted', 'FTP' and 'SSH'.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, looks like documentation and reality do not match. ;)

The question is where do you want to host your project. If you want to use git, just create your project on github and connect cloud9 to it.